# PagesController.php is not being recognized in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

I've installed cakephp2.0 in my project but now all my work that used to work in 1.3 no longer works in 2.0.

For example, the PagesController is not being recognized. When I go to my index page, I get an error stating that

```
Notice (8): Undefined index:  controller [CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 84]

Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to Apc cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 310]

Warning (512): _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to Apc cache [CORE/Cake/Cache/Cache.php, line 310]

Missing Controller

Error: Controller could not be found.

Error: Create the class Controller below in file: app/Controller/Controller.php

<? php
class Controller extends AppController {
}

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/View/Errors/missing_controller.ctp
```

I dont have Controller.php but I do have PagesController.php. I want my app to recognize the Pages not the Controller.php

How can force it to look for Pages and not Controller.php? Thanks!

Comment: I met this error, too  . Can't find out now. i can load homepages. but with other controller, Notice (8): Undefined index:  controller [CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 84].

Answer (score 1):

You need to either migrate your project to 2.0, or just stick with cake 1.3.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

I can fix error : `Notice (8): Undefined index: controller [CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 84].`
when add this lines in Config/routes.php

```
CakePlugin::routes();

require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```